# .trigger parameters won't be passed

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have this function it is from a plugin I use in wordpress.

```
this.changeColor = function(element, hex, temp, colorLinking) {
console.log('hex',hex);   
};
```

I want to trigger it and pass some parameters.

```
$('#fancy-product-designer-' + productID + '').trigger('changeColor', [obj,'#ffffff',true,true]) ;
```

But the parameters won't pass through the change color function.

The console logs: hex – false

What can I do to make the parameters pass?

Thanks in advance.

Greetings,
Robin

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```js
$(".btn").on("changeColor", function(element, hex, temp, colorLinking,lastarg) {
  console.log('element', element);
  console.log('hex', hex);
  console.log('temp', temp);
  console.log('colorLinking', colorLinking);
  console.log('lastarg', lastarg);
});

$(".btn").on("click", function(e) {
  $(".btn").trigger('changeColor', [false, '#ffffff', true, true]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="test" class="btn" />
```

[image: From chrome console]

Comment: It works I added my console output in my answer. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Hi,

I have a design tool.

http://dev.panel-it.eu/nl/product/ontwerp-sticker-effen-kleuren/

When I add an element I want to set it white by default.

You can see the log output, it show false on hex.

Comment: This is the function I am calling 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4258476/function%20changecolor.rtf